# Parse "27-11-17 02:13:17.921000000 PM" into "dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss.S a" in java

Tags: java

I am getting wrong output with following code.

```
String str = "27-11-17 02:13:17.921000000 PM";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss.S a");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(str).toString());
```

What's wrong with it.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing (with a full error message and stack trace where appropriate), and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.

Comment: Your snippet is working fine without any exception, please specify what output you want and what you are getting

Comment: can you pls provide that link of answer??

Comment: i am getting "Fri Dec 08 06:03:17 IST 2017" output. but it's wrong.how to get proper parse of that string.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the `SimpleDateFormat` class can throw a [checked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html), namely 'ParseException' which your method then needs to acknowledge for your function to compile. See below.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String str = "27-11-17 02:13:17.921000000 PM";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss.S a");
        System.out.println(sdf.parse(str).toString());
    }
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: it's give me "Fri Dec 08 06:03:17 IST 2017" output. but it's wrong.

Comment: That's because you've added 921,000,000 milliseconds to your time, which is apparently, 10.66 days. I.e. change `02:13:17.921000000` to `02:13:17.92`.

Answer (score 0):

So it is kind of strange what is happening. It expects 3 didgets for the milliseconds.  921000000 is being treated as what is says 921,000,000 milliseconds or a little over 10 days.  So it parse the date then adds 921000000 milliseconds to it to get Dec 8th.  This code got the date I would expect.

```
str = "27-11-17 02:13:17.921000000 PM";
str = str.substring(0, 21) + str.substring(27,30);
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss.S a");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(str).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone already mentioned that 921000000 is not a decimal fraction of seconds, but the number of milliseconds (by "the" international standard). Unfortunately java propagates the overflow to the seconds and so forth.

The solution is to interprete the "milliseconds" part as decimal fraction,
and truncate it:

```
String str = "27-11-17 02:13:17.921000000 PM";
str = str.replaceFirst("(\\.\\d{3})\\d+", "$1");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss.S a");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(str).toString());
```

This will still leave .9 as 9 milliseconds; if you would want that to hold only for .009, do a second replace:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("\\.(\\d{2})\\b", ".0$1")
         .replaceFirst("\\.(\\d)\\b", ".00$1");
```